# How to use PNG file to favorite icon in Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm used this code in nuxt.config.js

```
{ rel: 'icon', type='image/png', sizes: '32x32', href: '/images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png' },
```

but SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

How can I do that

Comment: Write `type: 'image/png'` instead of `type = 'image/png'`

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error in your objects where `type='image/png'` should be `type: 'image/png'`

Answer (score 2):

i added a query string to the favicon and it worked for me.

```
{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: '/favicon.png?v2' }
```

Answer (score -1):

I was not able to use a .png either. I made it with a .ico:

{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }

The .ico I generated from the png on https://realfavicongenerator.net and added it to /static folder.